# Every Nowhere Dense Set is Residual

Tags: general-topology

How Can I Prove the following proposition:
Every Nowhere Dense Set is Residual.
I have no idea how to prove it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

False. The opposite is true in complete metric spaces. If $(X,d)$ is a complete metric space and $A$ is nowhere dense then $A$ cannot be residual. If it is, then $A^{c}$ is a countable union of nowhere dense sets which makes $X=A \cup A^{c}$ also a countable union of nowhere dense sets contradicting Baire Category Theorem.